# Dictate placement of InfoWindow - ArcGIS 3.27 API

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there a way to dictate on which side of the point the InfoWindow shows up?

I have tried using `map.infoWindow.show(location, InfoWindow.ANCHOR_UPPERRIGHT)` thinking that this would make the window always show on the right side of the point, but it didn't seem to have an effect.

I'm trying to develop a way for the user to move the InfoWindow out of the way so that it doesn't block any other features that they may need to see, or in some cases block the feature that is highlighted. Even if I can't drag it out of the way, being able to move it 90 degrees would still help.

Comment: According to the documentation, your approach seems to be the right one.
Anyway I would set the FixedAnchor using map.infoWindow.setFixedAnchor(InfoWindow.ANCHOR_UPPERRIGHT) and see if it has an effect.

Comment: Your exact suggestion didn't work because the `.setFixedAnchor` function wasn't available on mine. However, using `map.infoWindow.anchor = "upperright"` seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With helpful advice from @Katah, I was able to figure out the problem.

Using `map.infoWindow._anchorSetter(pos)` where `pos = ("top" || "right" || "bottom" || "left")` allowed me to dictate the position of the InfoWindow relative to the point placed at any given time.